# My .vimrc file disabled the copy/paste action using mouse right click!

Tags: linux, vim, rc

Am using an open source .vimrc file from [GitHub](https://github.com/amix/vimrc/blob/master/vimrcs/basic.vim), but it is screwing up my default mouse right click, copy-paste actions. Whenever I do a right click, it enters into the visual mode and I am having a hard time, doing a copy-paste when I'm inter-working with my Windows machine.

Let me know what .vimrc config lines to delete.

Am running a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

Comment: In the file you propose, lines 105 -- 108 mention the mouse. Have you tried removing these ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @VincentNivoliers said in his comment, your issue comes from the line `mouse=a`.
It enables the mouse in all modes of vim, ie letting you put the cursor where you click.

`a` means this is active in all modes. If you don't want `vim` to care about your mouse, just set `mouse=` (no value). Then, you could use your mouse to copy'n'paste from your clipboard as in a terminal.

From [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html):

> The mouse can be enabled for different modes:
>
> ```
>   n   Normal mode
>     v   Visual mode
>     i   Insert mode
>     c   Command-line mode
>     h   all previous modes when editing a help file
>     a   all previous modes
>     r   for |hit-enter| and |more-prompt| prompt
> ```